# Calculate local and global extremums: $f(x) = (x^{2}+x+1) \cdot e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, optimization, curves

> Calculate all local and global extremums: $f(x) = (x^{2}+x+1) \cdot
> e^{-x}$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I'm pretty sure that I have created the derivatives and also calculated the local extremums correctly. But I'm not sure at all about the global ones. This means I'm especially / mainly interested in knowing if I did the calculation for the global ones correctly.

$$f'(x) = e^{-x}(x-x^{2})$$

$$f'(x) = 0$$

$$e^{-x}(x-x^{2}) = 0 \Rightarrow x_{1} = 0, x_{2}= 1$$

$$f''(x) = e^{-x}(x^{2}-3x+1)$$

$$f''(0) = 1 > 0$$

$$f''(1)= -e < 0$$

$\Rightarrow$

Local minimum at $P_{1}(0|1)$

Local maximum at $P_{2}(1|\frac{3}{e})$

Now for global ones, I would say we need to check the limits for $+- \infty$:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}e^{-x}(x^{2}+x+1)= 0$ $\Rightarrow$ There is a global minimum

$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}e^{-x}(x^{2}+x+1)= \infty$ $\Rightarrow$ There is a global maximum

Comment: The values $0$ and $+\infty$ are never really attained, I mean: for no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ do you have $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = \infty$. Presumably, you would therefore not call these global extrema (check the definitions in your source/notes/book).

Answer (score 1):

actually it is $$f''(1)=-e^{-1}$$
your other answers are ok, the extrema are called infimum or supremum

Comment: The global ones, did I calculate them correctly too?