# Calculate all local & global extremums of this exponential-function

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives, exponential-function

> $$f(x)=(x^{2}+x+1) \cdot e^{-x}$$

$$f'(x)=e^{-x}(x-x^{2})$$

$$f''(x)=e^{-x}(x^{2}-3x+1)$$

(Both derivatives are correct, checked this with an online calculator.)

$$f'(x)=0$$

$$0=e^{-x}(x-x^{2})$$

$$0=x-x^{2}$$

$$0=x(1-x)$$

$$x_{1}=0$$

$$x_{2}=1$$

Check if these are maximum / minimum:

$$f''(0)=1>0$$

$\Rightarrow$ minimum at $P(0|1)$

$$f''(1) = -\frac{1}{e}<0$$

$\Rightarrow$ maximum at $Q(1|\frac{3}{e})$

**Now check if local or global extremums:**

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(x^{2}+x+1) \cdot e^{-x}= 0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}(x^{2}+x+1) \cdot e^{-x}= \infty$$

Thus $P$ is a global minimum and $Q$ is a local maximum.

I'd like to know if everything is alright? The bolt printed means this is the part I care most about, the main reason I ask this question. Because I'm not sure if this is right, about the rest, it seems correct to me but who knows :o

Comment: I guess the domain of this function is supposed to be all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @MPW yes that's right!

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932843/calculate-local-and-global-extremums-fx-x2x1-cdot-e-x?rq=1.

Comment: Ok I calculated the limits and now compare them with the extremums I calculated. How can I know if local or global..? For $\infty$ limit is $0$ and I got an extremum at $x=0$ that's why I thought it is global. Or do I only have to look at the $y$ value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is not a global minimum because, as you stated, the limit of the function as $x\to \infty$ is 0. There is a value of $x$ where $f(x)<1 = P(0).$

And to check the rest of your work: [Plot of  $f(x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(x%5E2%2Bx%2B1)e%5E(-x)%20from%20-%200.5%20to%203)

Comment: Oh I had ti compare the $y$ value to know that, right? Because I compared the $x$ values. Please tell me if that's true :)

Comment: @klbrtree Correct. The value of the function is $y$, not $x$.